# SQL Query - Daily Attendance for students enrolled in classes

Tags: sql

I need help with a SQL query. It seems to be working but I need to make two changes:

1) If the student does not have any absences it should not show a row for him but it does not seem to be picking up.
2) If I want to display what class the student is enrolled from a group of classes what would be the proper method to do?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  s.student_number AS "Student Number",
  s.lastfirst AS "Student Name",
  DECODE(s.grade_level,-1,'PK',0,'KG',s.grade_level) AS GRADE,
  s.home_phone AS "Phone",
  DECODE(s.schoolid,280050,'Kodiak High School',s.schoolid) School,
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='1') AS "Per. 1",
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='2') AS "Per. 2",
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='3') AS "Per. 3",
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='4') AS "Per. 4",
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='5') AS "Per. 5",
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='6') AS "Per. 6",
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='7') AS "Per. 7",
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='8') AS "Adv",
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='9') AS "Act",
  (SELECT listagg(attm.att_code,'|') within group (order by attm.att_code) FROM pssis_attendance_meeting attm WHERE attm.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE) AND attm.studentid=s.id AND attm.att_code IS NOT NULL AND attm.period_number='10') AS "Clb"
FROM attendance att
JOIN students s ON s.id=att.studentid
JOIN cc ON s.ID=cc.studentid
JOIN sections ON cc.sectionid = sections.id

WHERE
  att.att_date=to_date(SYSDATE)
  AND att.schoolid in ('280050')
  AND s.enroll_status='0'
  AND cc.termid = 2700
  AND sections.course_number LIKE 'ACT%'

ORDER BY s.lastfirst
```

Comment: Table structures and sample data are helpful

Comment: You should specify the DBMS.  The 'Decode' function is apparently Oracle?

Comment: Sorry yes we use Oracle and the tables I am using is listed below: Students we list all the students demographic information, cc is where we have all the student enrollment, attendance list the attendance and sections is all the sections offered in the school. I am trying to display the attendance (only absences) for students enrolled n specific courses that starts with ACT and CLB right now I only have ACT on the query. I also would like to dispaly the class name.